# pyspark concat a string column based on a numeric-value condition on a different column

Tags: pyspark, string-concatenation

I am using PySpark. I have a df where I have to concat the strings in one column ONLY when the sum of the numbers in another column is <= 500.

Below is a full working mini-example code. On a per-date, per-term basis, I have to concat the "text" column only if the "number" values add-up to <= 500. Otherwise, for that date, term, there will be more than one row ...the first will be close to or equal to 500 and the following one the remainder of the sum.

In the below code, I tried to concat WITHOUT the <= 500 condition. And if you see, the row corresponding to 2023-03-10, wheel, , 700. The code has concatenated the text, but the total number has gone above 500.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, row_number, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')


date_list = ['2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-11', '2023-03-11', '2023-03-15', '2023-03-20', '2023-03-22', '2023-03-24', '2023-03-25']
term_list = ['wheel', 'wheel', 'wheel', 'credit', 'horn', 'credit', 'configure', 'door', 'wheel', 'trunk']
text_list = ['hello the wheel is bad', 'wheel are loose', 'wheel slippery', 'credit reports',
             'no horn ringing', 'my credit is missing', 'configure for family', 'door jammed', 'how wheel turns', 'trunk space']
num_list = [200, 400, 100, 400, 300, 300, 100, 200, 200, 300]

df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(date_list, term_list, text_list, num_list), ['date', 'term', 'text', 'number'])

print(df.show())


# create seq ids
df_with_seq_id = df.withColumn('seq_id', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
df_with_seq_id.show()

target_sum = 500

# This will concat texts that belong to each topic. But, ignores the max-limit of 500 token size.
#dfa = df_with_seq_id.groupby('date', 'topic').agg(F.concat_ws(", ", F.collect_set(F.col("text"))).alias("c_text"))
dfa = df_with_seq_id.groupby('date', 'term').agg(F.concat_ws(", ", F.collect_set(F.col("text"))).alias("c_text"), F.sum("number").alias("total_number"))
dfa.show()
```

Output of the above code:

```
+----------+---------+--------------------+------+------+
|      date|     term|                text|number|seq_id|
+----------+---------+--------------------+------+------+
|2023-03-10|    wheel|hello the wheel i...|   200|     1|
|2023-03-10|    wheel|     wheel are loose|   400|     2|
|2023-03-10|    wheel|      wheel slippery|   100|     3|
|2023-03-11|   credit|      credit reports|   400|     4|
|2023-03-11|     horn|     no horn ringing|   300|     5|
|2023-03-15|   credit|my credit is missing|   300|     6|
|2023-03-20|configure|configure for family|   100|     7|
|2023-03-22|     door|         door jammed|   200|     8|
|2023-03-24|    wheel|     how wheel turns|   200|     9|
|2023-03-25|    trunk|         trunk space|   300|    10|
+----------+---------+--------------------+------+------+

+----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
|      date|     term|              c_text|total_number|
+----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
|2023-03-11|     horn|     no horn ringing|         300|
|2023-03-10|    wheel|wheel slippery, h...|         700|
|2023-03-22|     door|         door jammed|         200|
|2023-03-11|   credit|      credit reports|         400|
|2023-03-20|configure|configure for family|         100|
|2023-03-25|    trunk|         trunk space|         300|
|2023-03-15|   credit|my credit is missing|         300|
|2023-03-24|    wheel|     how wheel turns|         200|
+----------+---------+--------------------+------------+
```

Can anyone please help to concat the text only if the sum(number) <= 500? I am looking at the 'when' condition during agg/concat_ws...but still have not figured out how to use it.

UPDATE: This is what I have tried...but doesn't work:

```
print(f'\nConditional concatenation...')
dfb = df_with_seq_id.groupby("date", "term").agg(
    F.when(
        F.sum(F.col("number")) <= 500,
        F.concat_ws(", ", F.collect_set(F.col("text")))
    ).otherwise(
        F.col("text")
    ))
```

Looks like my first argument to the 'when' condition is a bool instead of a Column-Type. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** There are several ways the texts could be concatenated. In the given example, texts with seq_ids (1, 3) or (2, 3) could be concatenated as both pairs belong to same date, term and sum(number) <= 500. I really don't care what texts are concatenated...as long as there concatenations that reach <= 500. To enable this, i created this seq_id col to figure out which seq_ids to merge...